# Create custom breadcrumbs table in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, breadcrumbs, laravel-5.4

I have categories which have child categories. This child categories can also have many child categories and many parent categories. So it is chained to it's children with Many to Many relationship.

This child categories can also have many products and this products can be in many categories.

I have two cases:

1. If product does not have custom breadcrumb it will get first category in it's categories and recursively go up until root with the same algorithm (getting first parent) and generate breadcrumb. (I have already done this case).
2. If we want to chose custom way to root category in possible many routes to it.

I can't figure out how I can create table structure to be more performance friendly. How to create a table structure?

One more thing. If category structure is changed, all related custom breadcrumbs must be rerouted.

Comment: I can't answer your question but have a look at https://github.com/etrepat/baum This package can help you by handling tables with children and parents

Comment: @JanWytze Thank's for answer but I'm handling parent child relations, that's not my problem. The problem is table structure for custom breadcrumbs. For example product is in 2 categories. Automatically breadcrumb will be generated from first category to the root, but the other category is more fitting to this product to be in it's breadcrumb...